# How can I see an indicator in the tester when I test an Ea?

Tags: mt4

How can I see an indicator in the tester when I test an Ea?

I use two indicators using iCustom function... but I cannot see those indicators while testing the EA...
Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

Just run your ea in visual mode then pause it button is just on adjacent side of visual speed control . Then attach the indicator and it done .